# Jetbrains (phpstorm): how to expand path of current file in navigation tree?

Tags: macos, file, tree, phpstorm

For example - file was found using CMD-Shift-N (Mac os). I see the path of file in the top of IDE. How to jump to parent catalog of file without clicking in navigation tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alt+F1` (Navigate/Select In).
You can also use `'Scroll from source'` button in Project view toolbar (the leftmost one).